# Display .PDf file in All Browsers (Mobile and Pc)

Tags: php, android, html, ios

I have a web site and  .pdf file in my Ftp.
I wanna show this pdf file in Android,IOS and Windows all browsers.
My page is written in .php Codes Like that

```
<?php
header('Content-type:application/pdf');
readfile("pf location");
?>
```

Android devices is Download pdf file.
Iso devices is show only frames not information
What Do I have to do display .pdf file in All browsers?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I would try PDF.JS Library.

**Example:** http://mozilla.github.com/pdf.js/web/viewer.html

**Website:** http://mozilla.github.com/pdf.js/

Trying to embed the pdf is going to cause the pdf to render differently in different browsers.